# Take mails of all users in my microsoft exchange Workspace

Tags: python, web-scraping, mail-server, microsoft-exchange

Hi i'm admin in a microsoft exchange workspace and i want to get all mails of the users of this workspace!
i found this approach to extract the data, but, is there a possibility to not pass the admin password? instead we can pass like generated credentials or something like that?

```
  from exchangelib import Credentials, Account, Configuration, DELEGATE

userlist = ["user1@domain.com", "user2@domain.com", "user3@domain.com", ...] # Liste des e-mails des utilisateurs
admin_email = "admin@domain.com"
admin_password = "password" # Le mot de passe de l'admin

credentials = Credentials(username=admin_email, password=admin_password)

for user_email in userlist:
    try:
        config = Configuration(server='outlook.office365.com', credentials=credentials)
        account = Account(primary_smtp_address=user_email, config=config, autodiscover=False, access_type=DELEGATE)

       
        for item in account.inbox.all().order_by('-datetime_received')[:10]:
            print(item.subject, item.sender, item.datetime_received)

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Erreur lors de l'accès à la boîte aux lettres de {user_email}: {e}")
```